Proving soundness of sequent calculus
I am currently working on a presentation about the sequent calculus for propositional logic.
In this video, the interpretation for sequents is given as $v(\Gamma \vdash \Delta) = v\left(\bigwedge\Gamma \to \bigvee\Delta\right)$
Now, if we want to prove soundness, wouldn't it be enough to show that the interpretations of the sequents in a rule are equivalent? For example, if we want to prove $\dfrac{\Gamma,\vdash \Delta, A}{\neg A, \Gamma,\vdash \Delta}{(\neg: l)}$, couldn't we do the following:
$\begin{align*}
        &\bigwedge \Gamma \to \left(\bigvee \Delta \lor A\right) \tag{Def. $\to$}\\
  \equiv&\neg\left(\bigwedge \Gamma\right) \lor \bigvee \Delta \lor A \tag{Double negation}\\
  \equiv&\neg\left(\bigwedge \Gamma\right) \lor \bigvee \Delta \lor \neg\neg A \tag{Commutativity}\\
  \equiv&\neg\neg A \lor \neg\left(\bigwedge \Gamma\right) \lor \bigvee \Delta \tag{DeMorgan}\\
  \equiv&\neg\left(\neg A \land \bigwedge \Gamma\right) \lor \bigvee \Delta \tag{Def. $\to$}\\
  \equiv&\left(\neg A \land \bigwedge \Gamma\right) \to \bigvee \Delta\\
\end{align*}$
I find this much more understandable and convincing than other proofs I have seen. Is there a reason why this is not the standard way, or is it just plainly wrong?

@MauroALLEGRANZA But since I have used equivalency, don't I implicitly show that if the upper one is true, that the lower one is also? Isn't the point of showing equivalency, that if the one side is true, then the other side must also be true?

But how to justify those equivalences? Why those equivalence rules are correct? Soundness theorem is an answer to those questions. Said differently, if you justify the rules of sequent calculus by other syntactical rules (equivalences rules), you are just moving the problem of soundness to another set of syntactical rules.

@Taroccoesbrocco given the context of the question, these equivalences clearly live in the metatheory, not the theory. Soundness is a translation from the syntax of whatever logic you're studying to the syntax of your "ambient" logic.

See Soundness as well as Proving soundness of sequent calculus rules.

@Taroccoesbrocco So lets say we assume that propositional calculs is sound, or that we have proven that it is sound beforehand. Would this method work then?

@Snek - Yes, at least for some rules (at first sight, all the sequent calculus rules with one premise). But I don't see how your approach would work for rules with two premises like $\land_R$.

@Taroccoesbrocco Since we want to say that both premises are true, my first guess would be that you could conjunct them together
